# Learning Prolog (cuts, lists, negation) push me in the right direction

Tags: prolog

I have the following base knowledge:
“*NBA players over 30 years old that have won at least 3 NBA championships are superstars. NBA players below 30 are superstars only if they appear on the front cover of a videogame or if they have at least 5 million followers in Twitter.*”

Define a unary predicate superstar that gives only one answer (true/false) to each query, when applied to a concrete person, e.g. superstar(pauGasol). The rules should only check a fact once (for instance, they should not check the age of the queried person twice). You can’t use the “;” operator.

You can use these data in your tests (4 of these 8 players are superstars, according to the previous definition):

```
age(kobeBryant,37).
championships(kobeBryant,5).
millionsFollowers(kobeBryant,9).
age(pauGasol,35).
championships(pauGasol,2).
videogameCover(pauGasol).
millionsFollowers(pauGasol,3).
age(marcGasol,31).
videogameCover(marcGasol).
millionsFollowers(marcGasol,1).
age(stephenCurry,28).
championships(stephenCurry,1).
videogameCover(stephenCurry).
millionsFollowers(stephenCurry,5).
age(klayThompson,26).
championships(klayThompson,1).
age(kevinDurant,27).
millionsFollowers(kevinDurant,13).
age(russellWestbrook,27).
videogameCover(russellWestbrook).
millionsFollowers(russellWestbrook,3).
age(dwayneWade,29).
championships(dwayneWade,3).
millionsFollowers(dwayneWade,4).
```

So what i did was this:

```
superstar(X):- age(X,Y), Y>=30, championships(X,Z), Z>=3,!.
superstar(X):- age(X,Y), Y=<30, videogameCover(X),!.
superstar(X):- millionsFollowers(X,Z), Z>=5.
```

We learned lists, cuts and negation last lesson.
Could someone push me in the right direction as to what should i use, so the age is only checked once, and if it's greater then 30 goes one way less then 30 goes other way, im new to prolog and programming in general.
I am not asking for a solution, I am asking for a push, hint.

When i will figure it out, I will post the solution my self hopefully.

Comment: In all honesty, the right direction is away from this concrete course. Just a few hints: Prolog is a *declarative* language, whereas your instructor now forces you to think in terms of imperative operations. The given facts do not follow the naming conventions of all other Prolog predicates, which `all_use_underscores` instead of `unreadableNamesLikeInJava`. You are taught to use low-level arithmetic, negation and `!/0` in addition to these problems. I have never before seen such an unsuitable and non-declarative task being given to beginners. My hint is to try to find a better instructor.

Comment: :)) thanks ahaha, yeah unfort that is not the case here ahahah ))   but i will write tomorrow what he expected us to do

Comment: A simple solution to satisfy the requirement is to use `setof/3` to collect the facts in several lists, for example, for the ages: `?- setof(P-A, age(P, A), PAs).`, and analogously for the other facts. (Note by the way how `person_age/2` would have been a *much* more suitable name for this predicate!) After that, you can simply walk through the lists in any way you want, because no further restrictions are imposed. Horrible solution to a completely nonsensical and counterproductive task. In this sense, a good fit... Judging from the above, your instructor may even like this way to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end i did it like this:

```
 superstar(A) :- age(A,B), B>=30, !, championships(A,C), C>=3.
 superstar(A) :- videogameCover(A),!.
 superstar(A) :- millionsFollowers(A,B), B>=5.
```

This is how the teacher wanted it to be, seems like that is way to complicated for something that can be done simpler:

```
 trichampion(X) :- championships(X,Z), Z>=3.
 socialmediastar(X) :- millionsFollowers(X,Z), Z>=5.
 superstar(X) :- age(X,Y), Y>=30,!,trichampion(X).
 superstar(X) :- videogameCover(X),!.
 superstar(X) :- socialmediastar(X).
```

Comment: The usage of `!/0` renders these programs *incomplete* in the general case. For instance, the query `?- superstar(X).` will in many cases only report a single solution even when there are several superstars below 30 that appear on a cover. A good Prolog teacher will point out the hefty drawbacks incurred by such violations of declarative properties. This is also a good example where using CLP(FD) constraints would be highly appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The request to access only once a DB table normalizes the AND/OR search tree. You could introduce a service predicate to discriminate a pre-condition.

```
superstar(X) :- age(X,Y), age_check(X,Y).
```

now, using the cut, you can actually commit to a branch

```
age_check(X,Y) :- Y>=30, !, championships(X,Z), Z>=3.
% other 2 rules for age_check, actually not using Y
```

or, avoid the cut, but use a correct domain disjunction:

```
age_check(X,Y) :- Y>=30, championships(X,Z), Z>=3.
age_check(X,Y) :- Y<30, etc etc
...
```